# Unable to install Redis Extension for PHP 8.3 MacOS using Homebrew

Tags: php, redis, homebrew, phpredis

I am trying to install `PHP-Redis` extension in `MacOS` for `PHP 8.3` using `Homebrew` but after installing I am getting this error.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.3.0/pecl/20230831/redis.so doesn't appear to be a valid Zend extension
```

Here are the steps that I took

```
pecl install redis
// Added ext-redis.ini and removed exetension entry from php.ini
```

This process worked for all other extensions like Xdebug and such but not for this one. Anyway to fix this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compiled PHP extension is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596247/compiled-php-extension-is-not-valid)

Comment: Yes that was it thank you. I am not sure why I had to use `zend_extension` for some and just `extension` for others.